# android sqlite database user input name

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm wondering how to take a string from an edittext and use that string as the name for my database.  For example: If I input "Orthometric" into an edittext, I want the database name to be Orthometric.db.  The database will consist of coordinates and I would like more than one for each area where coordinates will be collected.  I want seperate databases because I would like to export the coordinates to a csv (comma delimited file) and only want the area specific coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

get the name from user and then do :

```
db=(new SQLLiteDbHelper(this,userInputDbName)).getReadableDatabase();
```

pass db name in constructor to your sqlite class

and define constructor as

```
public SQLLiteDbHelper(Context context,String Name) {
        super(context,Name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        Log.d("tag","db version is "+DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```